# Undefined return from function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and i am  struggling to get array function return from jquery promise. The function return undefined, but i want array return. Anyone can give hit why i am getting undefined return ?  thanks

```
var actualData = $.getJSON('https://opendata-download-metfcst.smhi.se/api/category/pmp1.5g/version/1/geopoint/lat/58.59/lon/16.18/data.json')

function getWinddirection() {
  let windValue = [];
  actualData.then(function(result) {
    $.each(result["timeseries"], function(i, Daydata) {
      for (var i = 0; i < Daydata.length; ++i) {
        if (Daydata[i].validTime.split("T")[1] == "12:00:00Z") {
          return windValue.push(Daydata[i].wd)
        } else {}
      }
    })
  }).then(function(windValue) {
    return windValue;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return windValue inside $.each you are not in scope function anymore.

At the end of your first `then` there is no return value for next promise, so windValue is `undefined` in second then.

You dont have to return windValue inside $each, you just have to finish your iteration, then return value for second then.

```
function getWinddirection() {
  //first change
  var windValue = [];
  actualData.then(function(result) {
    $.each(result["timeseries"], function(i, Daydata) {
      for (var i = 0; i < Daydata.length; ++i) {
        if (Daydata[i].validTime.split("T")[1] == "12:00:00Z") {
          //second modification
          windValue.push(Daydata[i].wd)
        } else {}
      }
    })
    //third modification
    return windValue;
  }).then(function(windValue) {
    return windValue;
  })
}
```

Comment: the function return is still undefined

Comment: I'm not sure if inside $.each or promise  you change scope function. `let` key word is related to a scope, may you try to change `let` in `var`. I edit my code.